# How to create a 'traditional' Web Service with Node.js

Tags: web-services, node.js

I hope someone can give me point in the right direction. I want to replace a 'legacy' web service, that has defined contract, using Node.js. I plan to use Node.js moving forward and transition to more RESTful calls, but I still need to support a legacy app. that needs to make a traditional WS call. What's the best way to do this?... which modules are the best choice? Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: What do you intend by "traditional"?

Comment: Can you give examples of the legacy service, how it operates, and the types of calls you'd need to support?

Comment: By traditional I mean a the type of WS provided by Apache Axis, that responds to soap based request response. One that has an existing WSDL contract defined. Does this make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only module I know of that provides at least some support for SOAP / WSDL is [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap).

It allows you to write SOAP clients as well as SOAP servers. Maybe it is a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I wanted to be sure I'm not missing something obvious!